# How can i do something additional with this MySQL query? in php

Tags: php, mysql

```
$SQL = "
    DELETE male_users from male_users
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        select id from male_users order by date_time DESC LIMIT 0, 100
    ) t1
    ON male_users.id=t1.id
    where t1.id is null
";

if($row_male[0] > 100){
    $result = $mysqli->query($SQL) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
}
```

I'm using this query to delete all names in a list past the most recent 100.

However, each of the names have a URL of an image on the server associated with them. How can I use this query and actually get the names of each of the items its deleting into a `for` loop to delete their corresponding image URLs?

Typically I'd want to use unlink(URL)

With a join query such as this, how do I get the actual returned row usernames?

Comment: If so, you need first to select your data, then do deletion.

Comment: If you know how, a foreign key cascade on delete does just that, though a soft-delete might be desirable... If anything, you'd probably want to use a transaction, and only commit if all 100 rows are deleted in both tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First SELECT to get all the image IDs, then run DELETE combined with WHERE IN, and also unlink each image.

Pseudo code would be:

```
SELECT image_id, image_path FROM table WHERE condition;
```

Fill the results into an array, then:

```
DELETE ... WHERE id IN (your ids) // (1, 2, 3, 5, 100)
```

Then loop the array, and for each do:

```
unlink($image_path);
```

You didn't show us your table structures, but that's roughly how you could do it. And don't forget you need image server path, not the url, for `unlink`.

Comment: Any relevant code? can it be done in one query or do seperate querys, load the id's into an array of sorts and for loop them? sorry im not a SQL user.

Comment: I'd use two different queries, so yes, get the ids, put them in an array or something and then use DELETE...WHERE IN (your ids), no need to loop for the MySQL part, but you'll need to loop for unlink... 
No problem, everyone is here to learn. :)